# Why is Socket.IO adding two clients when only one is connecting?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

In my app, the user goes to the home screen, chooses their username, then navigates to another page, from which they can go to the page where the room is entered.

I have some code that increments a variable `clients` every time user joins a room. But, whenever a new user joins, `clients` is incremented by the amount of connected users. This is not the desired behaviour. My code is below:

```
app.post('/race', function(req,res) {
  let race = io.of('/race').on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user has entered the race!');
    socket.on('joinRoom', function(roomName) {
      socket.room = roomName;
      console.log(socket.room);

      clients++;
      console.log(clients);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      clients--;
      console.log("A user has disconnected");
      console.log(clients);
    });
  });

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/race/index.html'));
});
```

I have removed some functions from my code for brevity's sake. But the main functionality of adding users to `clients` is still there. When only one user is connecting and disconnecting, it works fine, but when another user joins, it adds 2, bringing the total up to 3. When a third joins, it adds 3, bringing the total to 6.

There must be some problem with the `socket.on('joinRoom` function - it appears to be being called the amount of times there are connected users. Note that `console.log('A user has entered the race!');` is not called twice.

Why is this problem occuring?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Server
app.get('/race', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/race/index.html'));
});  

const racesocket = io('http://localhost', {
  path: '/race'
});

racesocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user has entered the race!');
    socket.on('joinRoom', function(roomName) {
      socket.room = roomName;
      console.log(socket.room);

      clients++;
      console.log(clients);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      clients--;
      console.log("A user has disconnected");
      console.log(clients);
    });
  });


//Client
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost/race');
</script>
```

this whole piece of code is called every time a user does "/race" POST api. This is not needed, remove it from there, once the client is connected to "/race" in socket, it will automatically come in 'onconnection' callback.

So it looks u are having user number of times connection event callbacks instead of just one.

Comment: So I should move everything except `res.sendFile` out of the function? I'm a little confused.

Comment: added full code now, as i said, idea is connect to socket separately and wait for connections in server